# Removing a loop in lapply

Tags: r

I have a loop which I would like to get rid of, I just can't quite see how too. Say I have a dataframe:

```
tmp = data.frame(Gender = rep(c("Male", "Female"), each = 6), 
                 Ethnicity = rep(c("White", "Asian", "Other"), 4),
                 Score = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12))
```

I then want to calculate the mean for each level in both the Gender and Ethnicity columns which would give:

```
$Female
[1] 9.5

$Male
[1] 3.5

$Asian
[1] 6.5

$Other
[1] 7.5

$White
[1] 5.5
```

This is easy enough to do, but I don't want to use loops - I'm going for speed. So I currently have the following:

```
for(i in c("Gender", "Ethnicity"))
    print(lapply(split(tmp$Score, tmp[, i]), function(x) mean(x)))
```

Obviously, this uses a loop and is where I am stuck.

There may well be a function which already does this kind of thing that I am unaware of. I have looked at aggregate but I don't think that's what I want.

Comment: I benchmarked the code you posted against the three answers currently posted, and your code in this post was actually the fastest both for small and large test cases. The solution by arvi1000 had similar speed and the other two solutions were 2-3 times slower. This really highlights that replacing `for` with `sapply` or similar does not necessarily result in efficiency improvements. I would encourage you to use the `microbenchmark` package to investigate the efficiency of all approaches for your use case.

Comment: If you can do without print(), you'll have faster code. Also, 2 separate lapply's with Gender and Ethnicity hardcoded would avoid both the loop and additional *apply complexity.

Comment: Fyi, I ran a microbenchmark with `data.table`. Doesn't improve the speed in this tiny dataset compared to methods josilber mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest apply functions.

```
sapply(c("Gender", "Ethnicity"),
       function(i) {
         print(lapply(split(tmp$Score, tmp[, i]), function(x) mean(x)))
       })
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. I had something similar to this but it wasn't working. So obvious when you see it.

Answer (score 3):

You can `sapply()` over the `names` of `tmp`, except for `Score`, and then use `by()` (or `aggregate()`):

```
> sapply(setdiff(names(tmp),"Score"),function(xx)by(tmp$Score,tmp[,xx],mean))
$Gender
tmp[, xx]: Female
[1] 9.5
------------------------------------------------------------ 
tmp[, xx]: Male
[1] 3.5

$Ethnicity
tmp[, xx]: Asian
[1] 6.5
------------------------------------------------------------ 
tmp[, xx]: Other
[1] 7.5
------------------------------------------------------------ 
tmp[, xx]: White
[1] 5.5
```

However, this internally uses a loop, so it won't speed up a lot...

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 tmp[,1:2] <- lapply(tmp[,1:2], as.character)
 tmp %>% 
     gather(Var1, Var2, Gender:Ethnicity) %>%
     unite(Var, Var1, Var2) %>% 
     group_by(Var) %>% 
     summarise(Score=mean(Score))

  #              Var Score
  #1 Ethnicity_Asian   6.5
  #2 Ethnicity_Other   7.5
  #3 Ethnicity_White   5.5
  #4   Gender_Female   9.5
  #5     Gender_Male   3.5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code:

```
c(tapply(tmp$Score,tmp$Gender,mean),tapply(tmp$Score,tmp$Ethnicity,mean))
```

Comment: My original code was using a tapply within a loop so it's nice to see how this can be extended. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the reshape2 package.

```
require(reshape2)

#demo
melted<-melt(tmp)
casted.gender<-dcast(melted,Gender~variable,mean) #for mean of each gender
casted.eth<-dcast(melted,Ethnicity~variable,mean) #for mean of each ethnicity

#now, combining to do for all variables at once
variables<-colnames(tmp)[-length(colnames(tmp))]

casting<-function(var.name){
    return(dcast(melted,melted[,var.name]~melted$variable,mean))
}

lapply(variables, FUN=casting)
```

output:

```
[[1]]
  melted[, var.name] Score
1             Female   9.5
2               Male   3.5

[[2]]
  melted[, var.name] Score
1              Asian   6.5
2              Other   7.5
3              White   5.5
```

Comment: That's a very nice solution indeed, thanks. I really need to start using reshape2 more...

Answer (score 0):

You should probably reconsider the output you're generating. A list containing all of the ethnicity and gender variables together is probably not the best way to go about graphing, analyzing, or presenting your data. You might be best off breaking down and writing two lines of code instead of that one off using perhaps `tapply`

```
tapply(tmp$Score, tmp$Gender, mean)
tapply(tmp$Score, tmp$Ethnicity, mean)
```

or `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Score ~ Gender, tmp, mean)
aggregate(Score ~ Ethnicity, tmp, mean)
```

And then, perhaps you might want to look at your interaction even though you suggested aggregate doesn't do what you really want.

```
with(tmp, tapply(Score, list(Gender, Ethnicity), mean))
aggregate(Score ~ Gender + Ethnicity, tmp, mean)
```

Not only do these lead you to better separation and presentation of the fundamental ideas presented by the variables but your R commands are more expressive and reflective of the intent in the data of separately coding those variables in the first place.

If your real task is to go at a number of variables any of these can be put into a loop but I would suggest you still want the output not as one single list but as a list of vectors or data.frames.